Скрипт Standoff 2 для PerfectClick
log("CREEPER SCRIPT PRIVATE opr price option 4");

var CREEPER = Point.get();
var CREEPE = Point.get();
var CREEP = Point.get();
var CREE = Point.get(); 
var CRE = Point.get();
var CR = Point.get();

int p1 = ;
int p2 = ; 
int p3 = ;
int p4 = ;
int p5 = 10000; //скорость обновления
int osm = 5; //если заходит в осмотр перед покупкой ставь больше

var left = Point.get();
var right = Point.get();


long time = Time.getMillis();
Point p6 = Point.get();
Point p7 = Point.get();
p6.x = CREEPER.x -1;
p6.y = CREEPER.y -1;
p7.x = CREEPER.x +1;
p7.y = CREEPER.y +1;
var p8 = Point.get(p6.x,p6.y);
var p9 = Point.get(p7.x,p7.y);
p8.y = p6.y;
p9.y = p7.y;

var BRAWL = Point.get( left.x,left.y);
var STARS = Point.get(right.x,right.y);
BRAWL.x = left.x;
STARS.x = right.x;
startScreenCapture(2);
while (!EXIT) {
    if(getColor(CREEPER) == p1 && getContoursCount(left,right) > 2 && getColor(CREEP.x, CREEP.y) < 10000000 || getContoursCount(p8,p9) > 2){
        click(CREEP);Thread.sleep(osm);
        click(CREEPE);
        click(CREEPE);
        click(CREE);
        sleep(25);
        click(CREE);
        continue;
        } 
        if (getColor(CRE) == p3) {
        click(CRE);
        }  
        if (getColor(CREE) == p2) {
        click(CREE);
        }
        if (getColor(CR) == p4) {
        click(CR);
        }
        if ((Time.getMillis() - time) > (p5)) {
        click(CREE);
        sleep(25);
        click(CREE);
        time = Time.getMillis();
    }
}

Кто-бы мог расшифровать данный скрипт он для Standoff 2 для Perfect Click.
Данный скрипт является приватным от ютубера Крипера и он зашифрован, мне не известно как его расшифровать

Это не JavaScript

И этот скрипт не зашифрован )

Даже страшно отвечать, но хорошо. Данный код и не зашифрован, и не является JavaScript (но может быть его подобным).
Теперь, если Вы хотели узнать что он делает, ведь он "зашифрован":
Координаты CREEPER -> CR, а также их параметры p1 -> p5, osm. =>
Бесконечный цикл до выхода =>
Скрипт проверяет цвет пикселей в определённых точках и количество контуров, чтобы определить, когда выполнять нажатия =>
Вызов click().
